# Write a RGBA8 image as a R32UI

Tags: glsl, vulkan

I have an image with the format R8G8B8A8 (Unorm).

I want to write uint data on it (to be able to use atomic function).

So, when I want to "write" it, I am using in the glsl :

```
layout(set = 0, binding = 2, r32ui) restrict writeonly uniform uimage3D dst;
```

However, when I am performing something like

```
imageStore(dst, coords, uvec4(0xffffffff));
```

RenderDoc (and my app as well) tells me that all my values are 0 (instead of 1.0 (255 unorm)).

If I replace the `r32ui` by `rgba8` everything works fine but I can not use atomic values. So I wonder if it is possible to do such thing. (However, if I use a r32f instead of rgba8, it works fine as well).

Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vulkan specification guarantees that atomic operations must be supported for storage images (VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_STORAGE_IMAGE_ATOMIC_BIT) with only R32_UINT and R32_SINT formats. Implementations may add such support for other formats as well but it's not obligatory. So it's nothing strange that atomic operations don't work with rgba8 format.

Next. You can create an image view with a different format than the format of the image. In such case the image view's format must be compatible with the image's format. In case of the R8G8B8A8 format, both SINT and UINT R32 formats are compatible (have the same number of bits). But to be able to create an image view with a different format, image itself must be created with a VK_IMAGE_CREATE_MUTABLE_FORMAT_BIT flag.

One last thing - there is a note in the specification about format compatibility/mutable images:

> Values intended to be used with one view format **may** not be exactly
>   preserved when written or read through a different format. For
>   example, an integer value that happens to have the bit pattern of a
>   floating point denorm or NaN may be flushed or canonicalized when
>   written or read through a view with a floating point format.
>   Similarly, a value written through a signed normalized format that has
>   a bit pattern exactly equal to -2^b **may** be changed to -2^b + 1 as
>   described in [Conversion from Normalized Fixed-Point to Floating-Point](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#fundamentals-fixedfpconv).

Maybe this is the problem? Though it seems that there should be no conversion between rgba8 (unorm) and r32 (uint). Did validation layers report any warnings or errors? What layout is Your image in when You try to store data in it? Don't forget that:

> Load and store operations on storage images can only be done on images
>   in the VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHARED_PRESENT_KHR or **VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL**
>   layout.

Comment: I, indeed not use CREATE_MUTABLE_FORMAT_BIT and do not create several views. However, I do not understand why the following thing works : I create R32F image, and I use it as a r32UI inside the shader (using floatBitsToUint) and it works quite well. But maybe I reach an undefined behaviour that just make it works here, and does not work in rgba8 storage specifier.  And yes, my layout is in GENERAL_LAYOUT, and my layers do not tell me anything.

Comment: What format is the image view? The underlying image is R8G8B8A8_UNORM, but you need to bind a R32_UINT image view since you're using a r32ui format in the shader (see [#spirvenv-image-formats](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#spirvenv-image-formats)).